# enterprise architect scripting - modify position of DiagramObjects

Tags: scripting, uml, enterprise-architect

I try to generate an activity diagram with help of my external java program.
My problem: After I add an element (for example an Action) to the diagram I want to modify the position of it (left,right) because some elements are bigger than others.

My code:

```
Collection<DiagramObject> dobs = diagram.GetDiagramObjects();

//location calculation left out here
DiagramObject dob = dobs.AddNew(location.toString(),"");
dobs.Refresh();
dob.SetElementID(e.GetElementID());
dob.Update();

//center the position of the diagramobject on the left&right value
int horizontalDiff = dob.GetRight() - dob.GetLeft();
dob.SetRight(dob.GetRight()-horizontalDiff/2);
dob.SetLeft(dob.GetLeft()-horizontalDiff/2);
dob.Update();
```

If I check the values `Left` and `Right` of the `dob`-Object the values are changed. But when I open my EA Project they appears at the old position (before the centering code was executed).

When I execute the code to center all diagram objects after I opened and close the EA-Project it work's:

```
for(DiagramObject dob : diagram.GetDiagramObjects){
    int horizontalDiff = dob.GetRight() - dob.GetLeft();
    dob.SetRight(dob.GetRight()-horizontalDiff/2);
    dob.SetLeft(dob.GetLeft()-horizontalDiff/2);
    dob.Update();
}
```

But when I execute this without open EA-Project before, it changes the appearance not.
Anyone have an idea why it work's after open the EA-Project manually?
Here my goal in form of an image:
[image: my goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the `t_diagramobject` table.

Instead of using the SetLeft and SetRight methods, the elements in t_diagramobject have the `Top` and `Left` properties.

Put attention that the Top values are negative.

You Have to get the relevant element's ID from the diagram elements, then serch for this ID in the t_diagramobject and modify it.

Do not hesitate if you have any questions.

Comment: @flipperweid, do you need more help?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help, it work's now:) Sorry for my late work on it.